# Custom starting point of arrows in TIkZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    T1 & T2 & T3 & T4 & T5 \\
    & & & & Read x \tikzmark{a}  \\
    Read x \tikzmark{b} \\
    & Write x \tikzmark{c} \\
    Read y \tikzmark{d} \\
    & & Read y \tikzmark{e}  \\
    & & Write z \tikzmark{f} \\
    & & & Write x \tikzmark{g} \\
    & & & & Write y \tikzmark{h}  \\
    & & & & Read z \tikzmark{i} \\
    & & & & Commit \tikzmark{g} 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt, transform canvas={yshift=.25\baselineskip}]
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) -- ({pic cs:b});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) -- ({pic cs:c});
    \draw [->] ([yshift=.75pt]{pic cs:aa}) -- ({pic cs:bb});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

And the output I get is:

[image]

I am looking for a way to edit the starting and ending point of the arrows, so that they don't go over the content. TIA

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. In the future, please include a complete ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the `tikzmark` before the cell contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    T1 & T2 & T3 & T4 & T5 \\
    & & & & \tikzmark{a} Read x   \\
    Read x \tikzmark{b} \\
    & Write x \tikzmark{c} \\
    Read y \tikzmark{d} \\
    & & Read y \tikzmark{e}  \\
    & & Write z \tikzmark{f} \\
    & & & Write x \tikzmark{g} \\
    & & & & Write y \tikzmark{h}  \\
    & & & & Read z \tikzmark{i} \\
    & & & & Commit \tikzmark{g} 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt, transform canvas={yshift=.25\baselineskip}]
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) -- ({pic cs:b});
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) -- ({pic cs:c});
    %\draw [->] ([yshift=.75pt]{pic cs:aa}) -- ({pic cs:bb});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can use `\tikzmarknode` which allows more natural drawing commands for your tikzpicture. As @Qrrbrbirlbel suggests,
you can adjust `outer sep` instead of using `shorten`.

[image]

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    T1 & T2 & T3 & T4 & T5 \\
    & & & & \tikzmarknode[outer sep=1mm]{a}{Read x}   \\
    \tikzmarknode[outer sep=1mm]{b}{Read x} \\
    & \tikzmarknode[outer sep=1mm]{c}{Write x} \\
    \tikzmarknode{d}{Read y} \\
    & & \tikzmarknode{e}{Read y}  \\
    & & \tikzmarknode{f}{Write z} \\
    & & & \tikzmarknode{g}{Write x} \\
    & & & & \tikzmarknode{h}{Write y}  \\
    & & & & \tikzmarknode{i}{Read z} \\
    & & & & \tikzmarknode{j}{Commit} 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [->] (a.west) -- (b.east);
    \draw [->] (a.west) -- (c.east);
    %\draw [->] ([yshift=.75pt]{pic cs:aa}) -- ({pic cs:bb});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd add some `outer sep` to the nodes so that the lines don't start directly at the text. Maybe `.5\tabcolsep`.  (Inner sep is set to 0 so that the TikZ pictures don't use more space than they need.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Good point. I edited my response.

Comment: Thank you very much!